# Perl : getting an exact match from grep

Tags: regex, perl

I am matching the contents of 2 arrays like this:

```
foreach $headerLine(@headerLines)
{
  if (grep { $headerLine =~ /$_/} @filterLines) 
  {
      #do something
  }
}
```

I need an *exact* match here, but `^$_$` does not work. How do I go about it?

Comment: Maybe, you need to escape `$` by preceding backslash `\$` to match literally, since `$` is special meaning in regex

Comment: @Tushar, no, variable interpolation works within a regex.  Escaping it would stop the variable interpolation from working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a regex if you want an exact match.

```
if (grep { $headerLine eq $_ } @filterLines) 
{
    #do something
}
```

Your original problem was likely that `$_` had special regex characters, and these are treated as regex syntax rather than matching those literal characters. For example, if `$_` was `...` it would match any three characters rather than the exact string `...`.  This also might result in an error if the variable didn't contain valid regex syntax (e.g. `$_ = '('`).

You can get around this with the `\Q...\E` quote literal construct:

```
if (grep { $headerLine =~ /^\Q$_\E$/} @filterLines) 
{
    #do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I'd like to know how I can use an end anchor in this scenario though. `/$_$/` doesn't work.

Comment: I mean it doesn't act as a end of line anchor. For instance, it would match "energy" and "energy_g" too - while I want it to match only the former.

Comment: @AnupamaG, are "energy" and "energy_g" actual data that is matching?    Or is that just an example?

Comment: That's an example. I have similar data. That's why I would need to use an end-of-line anchor.

Comment: @AnupamaG, can you provide an actual example?  The end of line anchor should indeed work; I suspect the issue is related to your actual data.